# simple php form inserting "1" into all fields instead of varchar

Tags: php, mysql

so I have a simple database with two fields, name and email. both varchars and the database is MyISAM. I got it working and saving to the DB, but the input fields auto-populate with the number 1... and no matter what I enter into the input fields, the database saves 1 in the name and email fields. Is this because the php is outdated? Thank you and sorry for the shitty formatting...

heres my amazing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Subscribe to our Newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
       $name = $_POST["name"] || "";
       $email = $_POST["email"] || "";
    ?>

<h2>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h2>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<p><strong>Name: </strong><input name="name" type="text" width="50" value="             
<?php echo $name; ?>" /></p>
<p><strong>Email: </strong><input name="email" type="text" width="50" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php
if ($name == "" || $email == "") return;

$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

$db = mysql_select_db("databaseName");

$query = 'SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email = "' .     mysql_real_escape_string($email) . '"';

$result = mysql_query($query) || die("Could not run select query!");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo $email . " already exists in the subscriber database!";

}

else {

$query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (id, name, email) VALUES (null,"' .     mysql_real_escape_string($name) . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($email) .    '")';

$result = mysql_query($query) || die("Error adding " . $email . " to the  database!");

echo $name . " at " . $email . " was successfully added to the database!";

}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Heres the tutorial:
http://www.ehow.com/how_8368335_create-subscribe-newsletter-php-database.html

Comment: What's this `$name = $_POST["name"] || "";
       $email = $_POST["email"] || "";`?

Comment: honestly Its been so long since I've done php, I'll update above with the link where I got the code from... I think that is what is checking the name and email and putting it into the input fields.

Comment: *Hm...* strange syntax. Never seen that before.

Comment: $name = $_POST["name"] || ""; is equal to 1 as long as something is in the name field. Same for email.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's the PHP version, I think it's just a bad/incomplete tutorial. What you need to do is `$name = $_POST["name"];` etc., but first wrap your executable inside a conditional statement using `isset()` against your submit button and check to see if any of the elements are filled/left empty with `empty()`.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/DwxO5q

Comment: @Dagon So that's a boolean then, right? It explains it.

Comment: I remember from when I used to be decent at php what your talking about but couldnt even start to do that at this point... you mind writing that out for me Fred -ii- ?? I would love you forever... lol

Comment: I'm almost tempted to just make up a total rewrite using prepared statements lol

Comment: haha for sure, I mean its really just taking two input fields and storing them into a database, can't get much more basic than that. I just need a simple subscribe form quick to put on the homepage for a few days until I build out the rest of the site so I didn't need anything crazy

Comment: I rewrote it Mike. I've posted an answer below. Used `mysqli_`.

Comment: switching from javascript to php one can make the mistake of using $name = $_POST["name"] || ""; in javascript this construct would be right but not in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a go Mike:

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <p><strong>Name: </strong>
    <input name="name" type="text" width="50">     
    </p>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong>
    <input name="email" type="text" width="50" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'db');

if (!$con) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if( isset($_POST['submit']) 
    && !empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['email']) ){

$checkemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email = '".$checkemail."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

   echo $checkemail . " already exists in the subscriber database!";
   exit;
}



    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$sql = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO subscribers 
                         (id, name, email)
                          VALUES (null,?,?)");
    $sql->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
    $sql->execute();

if($sql){
   echo "Success!";
}

}
```

Comment: We are golden. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @mike You're welcome Mike. I made a slight mistake though, and when I tested it (after I posted it), gave me undefined index. I'll fix 'er right up and let you know.

Comment: @mike Please reload it Mike; I overwrote it all with corrections and you're welcome.